# Smallest required number of three comparisons in an optimal algorithm that puts any THREE distinct values into a list in ascending order

Tags: algorithm, sorting

**Question:**

> What is the smallest required number of three comparisons in an optimal algorithm (based on comparing values) that puts any THREE distinct values into a list in ascending order? What is the answer for FOUR distinct values?

**Options:**

```
a. 2 and 3
b. 3 and 4
c. 3 and 5
d. 3 and 6
e. 6 and 12
```

*I am preparing for AP exam and found this question [here](https://www.tracy.k12.ca.us/sites/clunetta/Java/practice/practice.htm).*

I know about Bubble Sort and Selection Sort and so I thought maybe Bubble sort should be the most efficient. So, I applied it on an imaginary list `{a, b, c}` and `{a, b, c, d}` and got the number of comparisons as `3` and `6` but the test page says it is incorrect.

**How I got `3` in first case?** - I had to compare indices `0, 1`, `1, 2` and then `0, 1` in the second pass - total `3` comparisons.

**How I got `6` in first case?** - I had to compare indices `0, 1`, `1, 2`, `2, 3`, and then `0, 1`, `1, 2` in the second pass, and then `0, 1` in the third pass - total `6` comparisons.

What is the correct answer and why?

Comment: Can you sort three elements with two comparisons? (hint: compare 3! with 2^2) Can you sort four elements with five?

Comment: Bubble sort in general is a terrible algorithm.

Comment: @JanDvorak I didn't know Bubble Sort is bad, it said "algorithm" so that's what I could only think. But how can I sort three elements with two comparisons? If I check `a<b` and `b<c`, and if the second condition evaluates false(implying `c<=b`), I still have to check if `c>a`. Maybe you could explain your comment in an answer? :)

Comment: _"...smallest required number of three comparisons"_ -- what are "three comparisons"?

Comment: @TedHopp I don't know :/

Comment: @TedHopp I'm guessing that's supposed to be a [three-way comparison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-way_comparison).

Comment: @user3386109 - Probably that's what was intended, But since the values are distinct, it seems silly to use that; a simple comparison (plus the assumption of distinctness) gives you exactly the same information.

Comment: @TedHopp I agree. Distinctness and three-way seem to be contradictory. Only the test writer knows for sure what was intended :)

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6145415/535871) on how to sort four distinct numbers with no more than 5 comparisons.

Comment: It says "an optimal algorithm". Bubble sort ain't.

Answer (score 2):

[Sorting numbers: minimal number of comparisons needed to sort n elements.](https://oeis.org/A036604) It show you that **c 3, 5** is a correct answer.

To read more about how this is computed (and why is it hard to compute it even for small answers), [read this wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort#Number_of_comparisons_required_to_sort_a_list).

For your exam, just remember that you can get exact answer as [image] for all n below 11, for every n bigger than 11 it provides a pretty accurate estimate.

Comment: How do you sort five elements with just seven comparisons?

Answer (score 0):

Let me guide you on how to solve this kind of problem.

First, the most important thing is to read the statement carefully.

> What is the smallest required number of three comparisons in an
>   **optimal** algorithm (***based on comparing values***) that **puts** any THREE distinct values into a list in ascending order? What is the
>   answer for FOUR distinct values?

1. The algorithm need to rely only on the ordering of inputs only (you got that right).
2. The algorithm is optimal. You need to know what that means. If you know bubble sort and Selection sort, you need to ask yourself (or google\wiki\so) if they are optimal. If they are, try to use them. As they are not, find out why. The lower bound for comparisons is **`Ω(n log n)`**. Some algorithms reach these bounds (heapsort, merge sort) in worse case. Bubble sort and Selection sort don't.
3. The thing is... those algorithms may be difficult to analyse, and going through sorting is actually a more difficult task than what was asked. The hint here is ***puts***.

How do you ***put*** an element in a sorted list? You ***find*** where the element should be and insert it at that position. Which incredibly common algorithm is suited for this task?

**Binary search**

If you don't know binary search by now stop and go read it.
You algorithm is the following:

> As long as the input list is not empty, take an element, perform
>   binary search on the sorted array (initially empty) to find its
>   position in the list, shift all elements with bigger positions than the position and
>   put your element there.

This algorithm is not a great general sorting algorithm because you have to deal with shifting elements. But that's not your problem. **Here anything but comparisons cost 0**. What it shows is that

```
Number_Comparison(n) = Number_Comparison(n-1) + binary_search_comparison(n-1)
Number_Comparison(n) = Sum(i = 1->n-1) binary_search_comparison(i)
```

The number of comparisons against an ordered list of k elements is `log(k+1)` rounded to the smallest value.

```
k = 0 -> 0
k = 1 -> 1
k = 2 -> 2
k = 3 -> 2
Number_Comparison(3) = 0 + 1 + 2 = 3
Number_Comparison(4) = 0 + 1 + 2 + 2 = 5
```