# what is the lower bound to sort 4 elements

Tags: algorithm, sorting

**Best lower bound for the number of comparisons necessary for any algorithm to sort any list of 4 elements in the comparison based model is ?**

I don't have the answer for this question. Just want to confirm whether i am right or not.

**My solution** = For lower bound, take any list ( here i have taken sorted list )

Ex: 1,2,3,4

If i apply bubble sort, then in one pass and counting only 3 comparisons (1,2) (2,3) (3,4) the list is sorted. So lower bound is 3 comparisons.

**And just to increase my knowledge, i am adding this also.**

If i also take upper bound on the number of comparisons.

Then, by decision tree,  i have

As height of decision tree will be log(n!), so answer would be log4! = log24 = 5

Hence , it will have atmost 5 comparions .

**Am i right for both the approaches ?**

Comment: The question isn't clear to me. If you suppose you know an algorithm that sorts any list of 4 by performing the least amount of comparisons, then your bounds are correct. Are you looking for a proof ?

Comment: What do you need the answer for?

Comment: @Nelxiost , The question is general . There is no particular sort .

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6145364/sort-4-number-with-few-comparisons. Potential duplicate?

Comment: I saw that. But still I m asking here lower bound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, it takes N-1 comparisons just to check that a list is sorted, so N-1 is a crude lower bound, and the information-theoretic bound is Ceil(lg(N!))~N lg(N) because you need to distinguish between N! permutations.

The latter bound is nearly tight but not perfectly, as cases are known where more comparisons a needed. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort#Number_of_comparisons_required_to_sort_a_list